# Get all platform event definitions via REST API

Tags: rest-api, platform-event

Is it possible to retrieve the list of all platform event definitions using REST API?

If I have an event name, I can get its definition using `data/v40.0/sobjects/<EventName>/eventSchema` but what is the endpoint (if any) to get all `<EventName>` that exist in current org?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrieving `data/v40.0/sobjects/` will give you all objects in the Org, including platform events.  Since all platform events end in `__e`, you can just take the result and filter out those whose name ends in `__e`.

Comment: Great! I hope that there are no potential issues like hitting the limit of the records per response, because I haven't seen any kind of 'next page' URL in the response